# c struct grabbing data by offset

Tags: c, struct, offset

Lets say I have this struct:

```
typedef struct nKey {
    int num;
    widget* widget;
} NUMBER_KEY;
```

and a function:

```
void dialKey(widget* widget) {
    // Need to print 'num' of the struct that this widget resides in
}
```

How do I go about accomplishing this? I tried something like:

```
    printf("%d", * (int *) widget - sizeof(int)); // Failure.org
```

edit: it is safe to assume that the widget being passed is in fact a member of a NUMBER_KEY struct

edit: looking for a solution to the problem not another method.

Comment: Your code wont necessarily work as is because there may be implementation-defined padding between members of a struct.

Comment: The big thing is that the pointer is to the widget, not the widget pointer.  Also, subtracting sizeof(int) from an (int *) moves that pointer back sizeof(int) ints, not just one.  Not to mention the possibility of padding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given just a widgit* and not a widgit** being passed into dialKey, there's no way to do what you want (a widgit* value has no relationship to the NUMBER_KEY struct). Assuming that you really mean something like:

```
void dialKey(widget** ppWidget) 
{    
    // Need to print 'num' of the struct that this widget resides in
}
```

Microsoft has a nifty macro for doing this type of thing (it helps with being able to have routines that manipulate linked lists genericly in C):

```
#define CONTAINING_RECORD(address, type, field) ((type *)( \
                               (PCHAR)(address) - \
                               (ULONG_PTR)(&((type *)0)->field)))
```

You could use this like so:

```
NUMBER_KEY* pNumberKey = CONTAINING_RECORD( *ppWidgit, NUMBER_KEY, widgit);

printf( "%d", pNumberKey->num);
```

Comment: +1 for `widget *` vs. `widget **` which all the existing answers have missed. `CONTAINING_RECORD` is clearly a hack, but at least it hides the gory details...

Comment: Very good point, I missed the pointer in struct declaration. I'll fix my answer accordingly.

Comment: @RBertig - it may be a hack, but it's a damn useful one.

Comment: You can simplify the CONTAINING_RECORD macro down to ((char *)(address) - offsetof(type, field)).  offsetof() is a standard C macro from stddef.h.

Answer (score 5):

As Michael explains in his answer, you cannot do it with given constraints because there's no way to "walk back" the pointer graph. To make things more obvious, let me draw a diagram of objects (in C terms, not in OOP sense) involved:

```
+- NUMBER_KEY --+
|  ...          | points to      
| widget field -+-----------+
|  ...          |           |
+---------------+           |   + widget +
                            +-->|  ...   |
                                |  ...   |
                            +-->|  ...   |
                            |   +--------+
                  points to |
[widget argument]-----------+
```

Notice the arrows. They are one-way - you can "walk" from a pointer to pointed value, but you cannot "walk" back. So you can deference `widget` argument of your function to get to the `widget` object, but once there, there's no way to tell who else points at it - including any instances of `NUMBER_KEY` structs. Think about it: what if you had a dozen other pointers to the same `widget`, some of them from different `NUMBER_KEY` objects? How could it possibly track that without keeping a list of all pointers within `widget` object? If you actually need this, it's what you'll have to do - make `widget` point to its owning `NUMBER_KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

The memory layout of a struct is defined by your compiler, your code would only work if you have 0 byte padding between struct members.  Usually this is not recommended b/c 0 byte padding would have your struct overlay across the standard read sizes of most processors.

Some useful macros for your problem:

```
#define GET_FIELD_OFFSET(type, field)    ((LONG)&(((type *)0)->field))
#define GET_FIELD_SIZE(type, field)      (sizeof(((type *)0)->field))
```

example:

```
NUMBER_KEY key;
key.num = 55;
int nOffSetWidget = GET_FIELD_OFFSET( NUMBER_KEY, widget);
int *pKeyNumAddress = (int *) &(key.widget) - nOffSetWidget );

printf("%d", * pKeyNumAddress );    // Should print '55'
```

Comment: If you #include <stdlib.h> or <cstdlib>, the offsetof() macro is standard.

Comment: I don't think it is going to work the way you expect. You are casting address of key.widget to *int thus pointer math with use sizeof(int) as arithmetic unit, so instead of deducting nOffSetWidget number of bytes you will deduct sizeof(int)*nOffSetWidget number of bytes.
And there is standard macro offsetof - no need to invent it.

Answer (score 0):

C standard defines `offsetof()` macro (defined in `stddef.h` header), which is handy in your case.

```
#include <stddef.h>

void DialKey(widget** foo) {
    printf("%d", *((char *)foo - offsetof(struct nKey, widget)));
}
```

Note that you have to pass an **address** of struct field, not a value!

Answer (score -1):

The safest solution is to keep pointer to related nKey structure in widget

```
 printf("%d", widget->myKey->num);
```

All other methods are unsafe

Comment: It is a bold overstatement to say "All other methods are unsafe".